# Why does the overflow:hidden didn't applied to my <p> element?

Tags: css, overflow

The overflow property didn't hide my overflown content which overflows the width of the element.

HTML

```
<section><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sed feugiat lacus. Morbi auctor, nibh vitae scelerisque cursus, nisl purus imperdiet lacus, quis porttitor ante mauris eget tortor. Vestibulum id molestie dui. Nullam sit amet ultrices ante. Nulla venenatis pellentesque mi, vel condimentum orci facilisis pellentesque. Aenean a enim ac dui tempus ornare eget nec nisl. In facilisis varius ullamcorper. Aliquam magna erat, pellentesque ut arcu et, accumsan placerat urna. Vestibulum porta justo ut laoreet dapibus.
Etiam dictum semper dolor, in laoreet turpis aliquam eget. Aliquam pulvinar sem lectus, vitae hendrerit libero pellentesque eu. Duis nec tincidunt felis, sed feugiat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sed feugiat lacus. Morbi auctor, nibh vitae scelerisque cursus, nisl purus imperdiet lacus, quis porttitor ante mauris eget tortor. Vestibulum id molestie dui. Nullam sit amet ultrices ante. Nulla venenatis pellentesque mi, vel condimentum orci facilisis pellentesque. Aenean a enim ac dui tempus ornare eget nec nisl. In facilisis varius ullamcorper. Aliquam magna erat, pellentesque ut arcu et, accumsan placerat urna. Vestibulum porta justo ut laoreet dapibus.
Etiam dictum semper dolor, in laoreet turpis aliquam eget. Aliquam pulvinar sem lectus, vitae hendrerit libero pellentesque eu. Duis nec tincidunt felis, sed feugiat.</p></section>
```

CSS

```
*, *::after, *::before {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body, div, p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


section{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 150px;


}
p{
  font-size: 1em;
  color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Codepen :: https://codepen.io/StinsonTheNoob/pen/oNbxjWx

Comment: the p is overflowing so you need to hide the overflow on its parent (section)

Comment: what is the goal here?, you want the text to disappear if it exceeds the first line on the right side of the `<section>` tag? Maybe explain how you want it to behave

Comment: add `overflow` to `section` not for `p`;

Comment: Please define your problem more clearly, so that I can answer up to your needs!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to not let the `<p>` start on a new line and rather not overflow, you need to set `overflow:hidden` to your `<section>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to disappear if it exceeds the first line on the right side of the

tag then put overflow: hidden; to its parent container which, in your case is the ...
But if you want that text remains inside the

container only then you have to make the

tag and the "font-size" responsive so that it adapts according to the width and then will not overflow!!!
If you simply don't want any scrolling of the page then kindly put overflow in html or body's CSS commands....